# clicking browser back button is opening a link in the previous page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using the below code

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strlink = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["link"].ToString().Trim();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.open('");
            sb.Append(strlink);
            sb.Append("');");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());

        }
}
```

In the page there are two links. When i click the first link it opens a window in a new page. I do this by using the above code.

I am clicking the second link in the page and navigating to another page. Now i am clicking the browser back button. Supprisingly its opening the first link.

How clicking back button is opening the link in the page.

I am using c# .net 2005.

Please help. Thanks.

Regards,`enter code here`
Radha A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your code is doing more or less exactly what you told it to... what do you think RegisterStartupScript *does*?

If you want the window to open only when you click on the actual link, then attach your javascript to the onclick of that anchor.

Comment: I have called the javascript in client click and its working now. thanks :)